# matlab2tikz/pgfplots: Tick-labels in axis cannot be overwritten

Tags: pgfplots, labels, matlab2tikz, ticks

I want to export plots from MATLAB to tikz and use matlab2tikz to do so.
Most of the data I have has dates on its x-axis. In MATLAB I use serial date numbers to store the time. I override the ticklabels with corresponding date strings before exporting. This works all very well - the only concern I have is that the decimal factor of the serial date numbers, `*10^5`, is not replaced or deleted. You can see it in the lower right corner of the following MWE.

My question is basically how to get rid of it? Do I have to do it in every figure, or can it be automated?

[image: MWE]

This code was used to generate it:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8} 

\begin{document}
\input{figure1.tikz} 
\end{document}
```

And the file `figure1.tikz`, which was generated by matlab2tikz and modified slightly by me:

```
% This file was created by matlab2tikz v0.4.7 running on MATLAB 8.3.
% Copyright (c) 2008--2014, Nico Schlömer <nico.schloemer@gmail.com>
% All rights reserved.
% Minimal pgfplots version: 1.3
% 
% The latest updates can be retrieved from
%   http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz
% where you can also make suggestions and rate matlab2tikz.
% 
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
unbounded coords=jump,
scale only axis,
xmin=735367.15,
xmax=735367.85,
xtick={735367.228472222,735367.492361111,735367.791666667},
xticklabels={{12.05. 12:00},{13.05. 12:00},{14.05. 12:00}},
every x tick label/.append style={rotate=45},
ymin=-0.2,
ymax=1.5,
ylabel=$P$ in \si{kW}
]
\addplot [color=blue,solid,forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
735367.179861111    0\\
735367.230555556    0\\
735367.252777778    0\\
735367.40625    0.205080000014277\\
735367.406944444    0.205080000014277\\
735367.407638889    0.205080000014277\\
735367.408333333    0.234419999960664\\
735367.409027778    0.234359999994922\\
735367.409722222    0.263640000030136\\
735367.410416667    0.263699999995879\\
735367.411111111    0.263639999975567\\
735367.411805556    0.292980000031093\\
735367.4125 0.292979999976524\\
735367.413194445    0.292980000031093\\
735367.413888889    0.292979999976524\\
735367.414583333    0.292920000010781\\
735367.415277778    0.322319999977481\\
735367.415972222    0.322260000011738\\
735367.447222222    0.644520000023476\\
735367.447916667    0.644519999968907\\
735367.448611111    0.673860000024433\\
735367.449305556    0.644519999968907\\
735367.45   0.644520000023476\\
735367.450694444    0.673859999969864\\
735367.451388889    0.673800000004121\\
735367.464583333    0.439440000009199\\
735367.465277778    0.410160000028554\\
735367.484027778    0.761699999966368\\
735367.484722222    0.849660000003496\\
735367.485416667    0.878880000018398\\
735367.499305556    1.05467999999746\\
735367.5    1.05467999999746\\
735367.500694444    1.25976000001174\\
735367.501388889    0.966779999980645\\
735367.502083333    0.673860000024433\\
735367.502777778    0.703140000005078\\
735367.513888889    0.908220000019355\\
735367.514583333    0.908159999999043\\
735367.515277778    0.908219999964786\\
735367.515972222    0.908220000019355\\
735367.516666667    0.703079999984766\\
735367.525  0.615240000042832\\
735367.751388889    0.410159999973985\\
735367.752083333    0.380820000027597\\
735367.752777778    0.38087999999334\\
735367.753472222    0.38087999999334\\
735367.754166667    0.380820000027597\\
735367.754861111    0.410159999973985\\
735367.755555556    0.410160000028554\\
735367.75625    0.410159999973985\\
735367.756944445    0.38087999999334\\
735367.757638889    0.351539999992383\\
735367.758333333    0.322260000011738\\
735367.759027778    0.292980000031093\\
735367.825694444    0\\
735367.826388889    0\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

Comment: See [Remove the scientific notation which is unreasonable](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119887/remove-the-scientific-notation-which-is-unreasonable): put `\pgfplotsset{scaled x ticks=false}` before the plot, then the scale label will be removed for all following plots.

Comment: @Jake thanks for the solution and the link as a broader resource :) That really helped a lot. If you want you can put that as an answer, so I can accept it.