# Using tkzpicture to generate graph of very close values

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm creating a set of plots programmatically.  Sometimes, the difference
between the max an min y-values seems to be less than the precision used to print the axis labels.  What is the best way to assure that the axis labels have
a sufficient number of significant figures to be meaningful?   I guess there are really two questions. 1) What should the plot look like to best convey the data, and 2) How to tell tkzpicture how to generate such a plot?

I'm showing the generated plot and the latex code below.
I'l be grateful for any helpful suggestions.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      ymajorgrids,
      yminorgrids,
      xmajorgrids,
      xlabel=Number of samples,
      ylabel=Average
    ]
    \addplot[color=blue,mark=*] coordinates {
      (345,31076.54)
      (707,31078.352)
      (1421,31079.246)
      (2811,31078.691)
      (5702,31078.664)
      (11191,31078.564)
      (22516,31079.123)
      (44882,31078.234)
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Possibly of interest: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119887/remove-the-scientific-notation-which-is-unreasonable/119888#119888

Answer (score 1):

How about this, where scaling is disabled on the y axis using `scaled y ticks=false`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      ymajorgrids,
      yminorgrids,
      xmajorgrids,
      xlabel=Number of samples,
      ylabel=Average,
      scaled y ticks=false,
    ]
    \addplot[color=blue,mark=*] coordinates {
      (345,31076.54)
      (707,31078.352)
      (1421,31079.246)
      (2811,31078.691)
      (5702,31078.664)
      (11191,31078.564)
      (22516,31079.123)
      (44882,31078.234)
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'll use that.  It's much better than what I had before.