# PGFPlots for small numbers

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

So i want to plot using PGFPlots but somehow i get bad locking plots. In Excel it looks like this:

[image: Excel]

If i try to make it with PGFPlots I get a super bad looking plot. What i want to have it the x axis simmilar to the plot in excel, but if i change the xtick or xticklabels i get errors.... Anyone got a suggestion ?

My Latexcode:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfplotsset{
      scale only axis,
  }
  \begin{axis}[
  width=0.85\linewidth,
  height=8cm,
    xlabel=$A$,
    ylabel=$B$,
 ]
    \addplot[only marks, color=blue]
    coordinates{
      (2.5e-3,20.29)
      (1.25e-3,21.46)
      (6.3e-4,27.61)
      (3.2e-4,42.23)
      (1.5e-4,57.95)
      (0.7e-4,68.51)
      (4e-05,70.15)
    }; 
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119887/remove-the-scientific-notation-which-is-unreasonable). You have to define the precision and to remove the scaling factor.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
    compat=newest,
    scaled x ticks=false,
    xticklabel style={
        /pgf/number format/fixed,
        /pgf/number format/precision=5
    },
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pgfplotsset{
            scale only axis,
        }
        \begin{axis}[
            width=0.85\linewidth,
            height=8cm,
            xlabel=$A$,
            ylabel=$B$,
            ]
            \addplot[only marks, color=blue]
            coordinates{
                (2.5e-3,20.29)
                (1.25e-3,21.46)
                (6.3e-4,27.61)
                (3.2e-4,42.23)
                (1.5e-4,57.95)
                (0.7e-4,68.51)
                (4e-05,70.15)
            }; 
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks alot for your answer. funny enough, your mwe is working for me, however if i copy paste it into my document it messes everything up and i get 20 or more labels on my x axis....

Comment: so you only want the 6 xlabels?

Comment: yeah. still i dont know why i get your result in a new file, and get a super bad looking plot in my main document..

any idea to reduce the amount of xlabels manually ?

Comment: Just add `xtick={0,0.0005,...,0.0025},` and `xticklabels={0,0.0005,0.001,0.0015,0.002,0.0025},` in your `axis` environment

Comment: thats does the job! great thanks alot. I still got no idea why its not working automaticly but its absolutly fine that way. thanks :)!

Comment: Would be interesting if you could ask another question with the problem you have with the number of xlabels, because i don't have the issue. But its up to you, since it works for you with my approach.