Decimal rounding in tikzpicture
I have the following problem. I have this code that creates a split bar chart for each day. Now I want to plot you numbers over it. Also with a decimal place, even if it is a whole number. unfortunately it does not work as I want, see the $4\cdot 10^{-1}$ in the plot but i want it as 0.4. I use precision=1 but it still doesn't work.
This is the code:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            width=\textwidth,
            height=0.45\textwidth,
            xlabel={\footnotesize Day},
            ylabel={\footnotesize Relative Revenue},
            ymin=0,
            ylabel style={yshift=-0.4cm},
            ticklabel style={font=\scriptsize},
            ymax=105.9,
            xmin=0,
            xmax=28,
            xtick={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28},
            ytick={0,20,40,60,80},
            ymajorgrids=true,
            grid style = dashed,
            enlarge x limits=0.03,
            bar width=5.2pt,
            ybar=0pt,
            x=0.5cm,
            axis lines=box,
            tick pos=left,
            xtick pos=bottom,
            nodes near coords,
            every node near coord/.append style={
                rotate=90,
                anchor=west,
                font=\tiny,
                yshift=0.03em,
                /pgf/number format/precision=1
            },
            tick align=outside,
            legend style={
                rounded corners = 3pt,
                at={(0.02,0.98)},
                anchor=north west,
                draw=black,
                fill=white,
                font=\footnotesize,
                /pgf/number format/.cd,
                use comma,
                1000 sep={}
            },
            legend image code/.code={
                \draw[#1, fill=#1] (0cm,-0.1cm) rectangle (0.2cm,0.1cm);
            }
        ]
            
        \definecolor{peachy}{HTML}{febb98}
        \definecolor{purply}{HTML}{75569a}
            
        % Behavioral Scheduling Approach data
        \addplot[fill=peachy,draw=peachy] coordinates {
            (1,41.55) (2,7.66) (3,0.00) (4,23.14) (5,53.1) (6,4.7) (7,62.96)
            (8,9.8) (9,1.5) (10,54.2) (11,46.6) (12,44.1) (13,67.2)
            (14,34.4) (15,16.7) (16,46.0) (17,46.9) (18,54.5) (19,62.2)
            (20,1.1) (21,6.4) (22,41.9) (23,71.3) (24,24.5) (25,13.4)
            (26,12.9) (27,30.5) (28,37.2)
        };
        \addplot[fill=purply,draw=purply] coordinates {
            (1,20.7) (2,8.7) (3,6.2) (4,16.12) (5,52.15) (6,70.55) (7,40.09)
            (8,20.53) (9,11.44) (10,20.46) (11,12.9) (12,54.87) (13,48.69)
            (14,6.26) (15,12.05) (16,55.71) (17,42.13) (18,41.29) (19,63.54)
            (20,33.00) (21,34.3) (22,64.88) (23,82.78) (24,23.64) (25,42.00)
            (26,43.77) (27,44.74) (28,43.69)
        };
            
        \legend{\footnotesize Option 1 \textcolor{white}{eady}, \footnotesize Option 2}
            
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{....}
    \label{fig:relunder}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

Additional. If anyone has any ideas on how I can make the numbers more aesthetically pleasing.

I don't see any scientific notation in the plot, but you can try scaled ticks=false: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/119887/47927 . What do you mean with "aesthetically pleasing" exactly?

Welcome to TeX.SX!

As I understand, you want to use a fixed format, with 1 digit after the period, even for whole numbers. The corresponding setting rely on /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill. So use
/pgf/number format/precision=1,
/pgf/number format/fixed,
/pgf/number format/fixed zerofill

Example, with some minor rewrites:

width=\textwidth was removed as the actual width is set by x=0.5cm;
axis lines=box was set at the beginning, as it resets axis labels;
ylabel style={yshift=-0.4cm} was changed toylabel style={xshift=-0.4cm} as xshift means an actual yshift for the y-axis;
xticks and yticks were simplified with the ... way, as suggested in comments by @Zarko;
font formats were removed from \legend (all is defined in legend style).

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      height=0.45\textwidth,
      x=0.5cm,% this sets the width
      axis lines=box,% axis lines redefines label styles
      xlabel={Day},
      ylabel={Relative Revenue},
      label style={font=\footnotesize},
      ylabel style={xshift=-0.4cm},% xshift means yshift for the y-axis
      ticklabel style={font=\scriptsize},
      ymin=0,
      ymax=105.9,
      xmin=0,
      xmax=28,
      xtick={1,2,...,28},
      ytick={0,20,...,80},
      ymajorgrids=true,
      grid style = dashed,
      enlarge x limits=0.03,
      bar width=5.2pt,
      ybar=0pt,
      tick pos=left,
      xtick pos=bottom,
      nodes near coords,
      every node near coord/.append style={
        rotate=90,
        anchor=west,
        font=\tiny,
        yshift=0.03em,
        /pgf/number format/precision=1,
        /pgf/number format/fixed,
        /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill
      },
      tick align=outside,
      legend style={
        rounded corners = 3pt,
        at={(0.02,0.98)},
        anchor=north west,
        draw=black,
        fill=white,
        font=\footnotesize,
        /pgf/number format/.cd,
        use comma,
        1000 sep={}
      },
      legend image code/.code={
        \draw[#1, fill=#1] (0cm,-0.1cm) rectangle (0.2cm,0.1cm);
      }
    ]

    \definecolor{peachy}{HTML}{febb98}
    \definecolor{purply}{HTML}{75569a}

    % Behavioral Scheduling Approach data
    \addplot[fill=peachy,draw=peachy] coordinates {
      (1,41.55) (2,7.66) (3,0.00) (4,23.14) (5,53.1) (6,4.7) (7,62.96)
      (8,9.8) (9,1.5) (10,54.2) (11,46.6) (12,44.1) (13,67.2)
      (14,34.4) (15,16.7) (16,46.0) (17,46.9) (18,54.5) (19,62.2)
      (20,1.1) (21,6.4) (22,41.9) (23,71.3) (24,24.5) (25,13.4)
      (26,12.9) (27,30.5) (28,37.2)
    };
    \addplot[fill=purply,draw=purply] coordinates {
      (1,20.7) (2,8.7) (3,6.2) (4,16.12) (5,52.15) (6,70.55) (7,40.09)
      (8,20.53) (9,11.44) (10,20.46) (11,12.9) (12,54.87) (13,48.69)
      (14,6.26) (15,12.05) (16,55.71) (17,42.13) (18,41.29) (19,63.54)
      (20,33.00) (21,34.3) (22,64.88) (23,82.78) (24,23.64) (25,42.00)
      (26,43.77) (27,44.74) (28,43.69)
    };

    \legend{Option 1, Option 2}

  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



For writing tick exist shorter way to write them: xtick={1,2,...,28},  ytick={0,20,...,80}, ... (+1)

@Zarko I was focused on OP's issue, I didn't pay attention to the full setting. I edited my answer. Thanks

@jlab Thank you for reminding me that it is not at all a good idea to use adjustbox, I will delete the previous comments
